# Merge and matching tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, merge, match

Does anyone know how to merge two tables with a common column name and data into a single table? The shared column is a date column. This is part of a project at work, no one here quite knows how it works. Any help would be appreciated.

```
table A 
Sub      Temp      Weight    Silicon   Cast_Date
108     2675       2731      0.7002    18-jun-11 18:45
101     2691       3268      0.6194    18-jun-11 20:30
107     2701       6749     0.6976      18-jun-11 20:30
113     2713       2112      0.6616      18-jun-11 20:30
116     2733       3142      0.7382     19-jun-11 05:46
121     2745       2611     0.6949      19-jun-11 00:19
125     2726       1995      0.644      19-jun-11 00:19


table B
Si      Temperature    Sched_Cast_Date     Treadwell
0.6622  2542    01-APR-11 02:57            114
0.6622  2542    01-APR-11 03:07             116
0.7516  2526    19-jun-11 05:46            116
0.7516  2526    01-APR-11 03:40            107
0.6741  2372    01-APR-11 04:03            107
0.6206  2369    01-APR-11 09:43            114
0.6741  2372    19-jun-11 00:19            125
```

the results would look like:

```
Subcar Temp  Weight Silicon Cast_Date          SI     Temperature Sched_Cast_Date Treadwell
116    2733   3142  0.7382   19-jun-11 05:46   0.7516  2526   19-jun-11 05:46    116
125    2726   1995  0.644    19-jun-11 00:19   0.6741  2372   19-jun-11 00:19    125
```

I would like to run a query that returns a results data only where `Sched_Cast_Date` and `Cast_Date` are the same. A table with the same qualities would work just as well.

I hope that this makes more sense.

Comment: What does it mean to merge two tables?  Can you post the DDL for the two tables?  Can you explain what the output should look like?  Do you want to create a third table?  Copy the data from one of the tables into another?  Run a query that just returns data from both?

Comment: There are at least 4-5 Different ways your Question can be interpreted. Can you post some sample Data And Tables as Justin suggested?

Comment: ok, I have edited it with some sample data and a "table"/example of what I would like the results to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to join two tables on a common column?  i.e.

```
select a.Sub, a.Temp, a.Weight a.Silicon a.Cast_Date, b.SI,
       b.Temperature, b.Sched_Cast_Date, b.Treadwell
from a
join b on b.sched_cast_date = a.cast_date
```